# Golang: loop through fields of a struct modify them and and return the struct?

Tags: go, reflection, struct, interface

I am trying to loop through the individual fields of a struct applying a function to each field and then return the original struct as a whole with the modified field values.
Obviously, this would not present a challenge if it were for one struct but I need the function to be dynamic.
For this instance, I am referencing the Post and Category struct as shown below

```
type Post struct{
    fieldName           data     `check:"value1"
    ...
}

type Post struct{
    fieldName           data     `check:"value2"
    ...
}
```

I then have a switch function that loops through the respective fields of the structs and depending on what value the `check` has, applies a function to that field's `data` as follows

```
type Datastore interface {
     ...
}

 func CheckSwitch(value reflect.Value){
    //this loops through the fields
    for i := 0; i < value.NumField(); i++ { // iterates through every struct type field
        tag := value.Type().Field(i).Tag // returns the tag string
        field := value.Field(i) // returns the content of the struct type field

        switch tag.Get("check"){
            case "value1":
                  fmt.Println(field.String())//or some other function
            case "value2":
                  fmt.Println(field.String())//or some other function
            ....

        }
        ///how could I modify the struct data during the switch seen above and then return the struct with the updated values?


}
}

//the check function is used i.e 
function foo(){ 
p:=Post{fieldName:"bar"} 
check(p)
}

func check(d Datastore){
     value := reflect.ValueOf(d) ///this gets the fields contained inside the struct
     CheckSwitch(value)

     ...
}
```

How do I, in essence, re-insert the modified values after the switch statement in `CheckSwitch` back into the struct specified by the interface in the above example.
Please let me know if you need anything else.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `field` has type `reflect.Value`. Call the [Set*](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Set) methods on `field` to set the fields in the struct. For example:

```
 field.SetString("hello")
```

sets the the struct field to "hello".

You must pass a pointer to the struct if you want to retain the values:

```
function foo(){ 
    p:=Post{fieldName:"bar"} 
    check(&p)
}

func check(d Datastore){
   value := reflect.ValueOf(d)
   if value.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
      // error
   }
   CheckSwitch(value.Elem())
   ...
}
```

Also, the field names must be [exported](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers).

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/0Uqf8Qi0lC)

Comment: Hey Thanks for answering! After setting the field values  would I then need to return `reflect.Value`? How would I re-insert this into the struct specified i.e. `Post` in this case for further use?